# Do all clickonce files need to be in the manifest?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a client/server app where the client is deployed using clickonce via a url hosted on the server. Each customer has their own server. I have some plugin dlls (for the client side) that I want to optionally offer to different customers, but I don't want to install dlls into the clickonce manifest for customers that wont use (or pay for) the plugins.

Is there any way around having to create a customized clickonce manifest for each customer which contains their selected list of plugins?

Comment: You can't do it via VS.  You can either do it manually by fiddling with the manifest or use a tool that allows you to create multiple _profiles_ such as via _[ClickOnceMore](http://www.clickoncemore.net/)_ each with customised binaries and options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions here:

1. Do all clickonce files need to be in the manifest?

   Yes, all the files you want to deploy must be included on the manifest.
2. Is there any way around having to create a customized clickonce manifest for each customer which contains their selected list of plugins?

   No, you will need to create a custom manifest for each client. In order to do this you can use the mage/mageUI tool from Microsoft SDKs (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows) Available for all .Net Framework versions.

With this tool you can create manifests from scratch, edit them, sign with your digital certificate, etc. You can do it using the UI option or command prompt if you want to automate the process.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @spectacularbob you are right, I already changed the answer based on your observation.